# ColorRamp does not invert properly

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, shaders, masking

I have a gradient texture in a colorramp to control a mask for shading, but it is masking the opposite part of what I want. This is what I have:

[image]

And I want to have this, but opposite, where the white is where the black is and the black is where the white is. So of course I used an invert node because that's what it does right? apparently not exactly, because this is what I got when I plugged it in:

[image]

So yeah, how do I invert it properly?

Comment: You can just swap the two sliders on the ColorRamp and lack the Invert node with the same result. Probably what we see on the pictures is a kind of illusion, the nodes are works right. May be you have to adjust the ColorRamp to enlarge the black region.

Comment: Your original white strip is a range of values from (just over) 0 to 1, the invert node will take value .8 and make it .2, for example.

Comment: A color ramp with two white stops on either end, and one or two black stops in the middle might give you what you want

Comment: Just because the textures _look_ different, when they've been through whatever view transform they've been put through, for your display device (sRGB?), and then, your display device, doesn't mean they _are_  different, from the POV of masking. If you put both  gradients through the same threshold ( _Math > Less Than_ say, 0.5 ,) The edges should match.

Comment: why don't you just use a math operation after the colorramp (1 - x) where x is the result of the colorramp?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with *Invert* if you had a pure black and white mask (values of 0 and 1, and nothing in between).

You can turn your current mask into this with a *Math* -> *Divide* node like so.  Be sure to check the *Clamp* option.

[image]

The *Invert* will simply swap the colors.

However, since you've built a gradient, and I assume you want all of those values in between, the easiest way is probably to duplicate your *ColorRamp* and modify the stops.

[image]